# Подключить Material Design Icons

Tags: html, css, material-design

html: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

css: `.item-main-ldown:before
        position: absolute
        content: '\f31d'
        display: block
        font-family: "Material Icons"
        color: #ffffff
        left: 0
        top: 90px
        font-size: 46px`

не отображается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему именно такой иконки нет в этом шрифте - '\f31d'. Если заменить на любую другую из этого https://gist.github.com/loicbisiere/31f3ee50337e305f02564ab2c67a72fa списка (например '\eb3b') , то все отображается правильно.

Альтернативный вариант - Можно вот здесь посмотреть https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline , и в before писать название, например

```
.item-main-ldown:before
        position: absolute
        content: 'accessibility'
        display: block
        font-family: "Material Icons"
        color: #ffffff
        left: 0
        top: 90px
        font-size: 46px
```

Comment: Спасибо. А где можно визуально глянуть на эти иконки?

Comment: @Proshka дополнил ответ.